# itext 2.7.1.jar or iText 5.x API method (com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.setLeading(float)) not reflecting leading output

Tags: itext

We are using itext 2.7.1.jar to generated the pdf file with contents.
Our requirement is to implement the leading (spacing between lines of text) in the generated pdf.
so we have **used the given method (com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.setLeading(float)) but it is not reflecting leading output**, there is no extra space appearing between the lines after specifying any value in setLeading(float) method.

Same we have verified using version iText 5.x , **need help on this issue.**

we have verified using version iText 5.x also

Our requirement is to implement the leading (spacing between lines of text) in the generated pdf.
so we have **used the given method (com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.setLeading(float)) but it is not reflecting leading output**, there is no extra space appearing between the lines after specifying any value in setLeading(float) method.

Comment: *"We are using itext 2.7.1.jar to generated the pdf file with contents."* - How are you doing so? Depending on how you generate the content, leading may have to be applied differently.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the ways to apply leading using this method PdfContentByte.setLeading(float) of itext 2.7.1 API

Comment: *"Can you please elaborate the ways to apply leading using this method PdfContentByte.setLeading(float)"* - setting the leading with that setter controls the leading of text thereafter drawn using `newlineShowText(...)` or with `newlineText(...)` inbetween. That leading setting is also changed if you call `moveTextWithLeading(...)`.

Comment: As mkl mentioned: Show us your code. Also see [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).